# How to retain Listbox visualization with high resolution images in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am in between of developing a document scanning application,

In that i need to save more than 50 images in a single document. So my issue is during the time of loading the saved images to listbox, i think i am loosing the visualization of listbox, And hence the memory consumption increases dramatically and caused application crash.

How i can load this images to listbox, without loosing the visualization of listbox?

Comment: May be you need create thumbnail images (with resolution 200*200 for ex.) only for present it in ListBox?

Comment: Can you please suggest effective method of displaying image, ie during the time of saving, which method is better. saving the thumb during the time of document creation, or re sizing the thumb during the time of binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my current project (winrt) I have similar problem and solved it by resizing images during binding (in getter of nested field)

```
  get
     {
          return new BitmapImage(new Uri(url)) { DecodePixelWidth = 200 };
     }
```

Hope it's help you too.